# pywin32 how to use PyCwnd.HookMessage

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

```py
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(None, None, "TXGuiFoundation", None)
```

I want to hook a window and receive its messages.
got the `hwnd variable` (`type(hwnd)` is int), but how to convert it into `PyCwnd` and use `PyCwnd.HookMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

`PyCwnd` is a base window class. Encapsulates an [`MFC CWnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160) class.

So you can refer to [CWnd::FromHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#fromhandle):

> Returns a pointer to a CWnd object when given a handle to a window. If
> a CWnd object is not attached to the handle, a temporary CWnd object
> is created and attached.

Also you can use `win32ui.CreateWindowFromHandle`, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788036/python-win32api-sendmesage).

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.